# Dynamically add methods to an object

Tags: php

I am, for fun, trying to make it able to give an array some options and then implode the array into a string which can be used with the WideImage class. But I am having troubles. It's like it's actually not possible.

My code is following:

```
$options = array('resize'=>'50,50');

$actions = implode('->', $options);
$img = WideImage::load($image) . $actions . ';';
```

This would make a string like:

```
WideImage::load('../images/photo.jpg')->resize(50,50);
```

What I am searching for from you guys, is to tell me if this is possible at all.

**UPDATE**

When I am using eval() I am getting an error that the methods given to the wideimage class is undefined property.

Here is my code:

```
$actions = 'resize(50,50)';
return eval('WideImage::load($image)->$actions->saveToFile('path/to/file')');
```

This gives me an error of undefined property, and says that saveToFile() is member of a non-object. But if I hardcode the resize and don't use $actions it's actually working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could pass that string to the [eval() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call_user_func_array is perfect for this, but you would need to refactor a few things.

```
$options = array('method' => 'resize', 'parameters' => array(50, 50));
$obj = WideImage::load($image);
call_user_func_array(array($obj, $options['method']), $options['parameters']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're about method chaining. Yes its possible. For first You must change the static call by creating new object, then each method must return the object. On your example:

```
<?php
class WideImage
{
    public function load($filepath){
        // your code
        return $this;
    }
    public function resize($width, $height){
        // your code
        return $this;
    }
}
$objWide = new WideImage();
$objWide -> load('../images/photo.jpg') -> resize(50,50);
```